# ember js radiobutton implementation not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've found an implementation of a radio button for ember js: http://jsfiddle.net/9HeQG/ but it has an issue that I can't figure out how to solve.

If you try to set the value that is bound to the radio button via ember set method, the check from the radiobutton is not being updated.

However, if you press to a radio button you can see that property is bound:

```
App.set('radio1', 'Dog');
```

but you can't change it with the set method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bootstrap.RadioGroup](https://github.com/pjlammertyn/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/packages/ember-bootstrap/lib/views/radio_button_group.js).

```
{{view Bootstrap.RadioGroup 
  contentBinding="controller.questions" 
  valueBinding="content.checkedQuestionId"}}
```

result:

[image]